# Jquery Resizable problem after class is added with live()

Tags: jquery, live, resizable

resizable() no longer works when the created div is clicked. All i'm doing is adding a class with live(). What is the solution to this problem.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.7/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" type="text/css" media="all" /> 
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.4.4.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.7/jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 

<style>
    .aaa { width:100px; height:100px;background-color:#ccc;margin-bottom:5px;}
    p{widht:500px; height:500px; margin:0px; padding:0px;border:2px solid red;color:#000;}
</style>


<button>Click to create divs</button>
<p id="ptest"></p>

<script type="text/javascript">
var dividcount = 1;

$("button").click(function() {
    var myDiv = $('<div id=lar' + dividcount + ' class=aaa></div>');
    $(myDiv).resizable().draggable().appendTo('#ptest');

    dividcount++;
});

$('div').live('click', function() {

    $('div').removeClass('selected');
    $('div').html('');

    $(this).addClass('selected');
    $(this).html('div #' + this.id);
});
</script>
```

Comment: You can test here: http://jsfiddle.net/sje397/RCdUv/

Comment: No it's not working. You are able to drag and resize at first before the div is clicked , but once you click the div, you lose the resize functionality and you are no longer able to resize the div. Drag is no issue, just resize.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because of this:

```
$('div').html('');
```

You clear out the HTML inside the div. When you make something resizable, jQuery UI adds some content that it needs. For example:

```
<div id="lar1" class="aaa ui-resizable ui-draggable" style="position: absolute; top: 38px; left: 12px; width: 125px; height: 120px; ">
  <div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-e"></div>
  <div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-s"></div>
  <div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-se ui-icon ui-icon-gripsmall-diagonal-se" style="z-index: 1001; "></div>
</div>
```

One way to address this issue is to put your text in a specific container and modify that, e.g.:

```
    $('div').live('click', function() {

        $('div').removeClass('selected');
        $('div .my-text').remove();

        $(this).addClass('selected');
        $('<div class="my-text">div #' + this.id + '</div>').appendTo($(this));
    });
```

Comment: Yes you are right, but how do we overcome this issue. I need to display text inside the div when it's clicked on, and clear the text and add it to the other div and the other div is clicked on,

Comment: @alex - I added something that might help.

Comment: With remove, you are removing the whole div. This is not what is needed. We only need to remove the text inside the div. The whole point is to only have the text show inside the clicked div. This is already happening working in my code, but resizable() is not longer working.

Comment: @alex: The selector I used ("div .my-text") is removing only the div I added to contain the text, not the original div created by the button. You could make that a `span` if you want, or anything - but the point of my workaround, and my recommendation, is that you wrap your text in _any_ kind of element, and manipulate the wrapper.

Comment: @alex: see this updated demo which uses the technique above and works fine: http://jsfiddle.net/sje397/bWYgj/